# How to toggle two buttons on mouse hover?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've two buttons:
1 - Follow
2 - Unfollow

At first glance the Follow button will be displayed and then when you hover over the Follow button, then I want to make the follow button to disappear and Unfollow button to appear, then after once hovered over the Unfollow button then I want the Follow button to appear and Unfollow button to dispear, so I how do I do it?

Feed backs are welcomed.

#### HTML CODE

```
<div class="btn-follow">Follow</div>
<div class="btn-unfollow">Unfollow</div>
```

#### CSS CODE

```
.btn-follow {
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: #38B7EA;
    padding: 5px 0;
    width: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
.btn-unfollow {
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: #A5BECB;
    padding: 5px 0;
    width: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
```

Comment: how about changing the text of the same `button` on toggle??

Comment: I want the background also to change

Comment: that can be done too...

Comment: @Mohamed Are you sure about `hover` or you mean `click`?

Comment: @Tushar Boths ways also fine. Can that be done?

Comment: Where is the jQuery you tried?

Comment: You dont want to use javascript?

Comment: You might want to use `outline: none` to hide the blue border around your button on Chrome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An alternative and more optimal solution as I said which can be done for same button as below:

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/kq0ajaxd/)**

**HTML**

```
<button id="followUnFollow" class="followUnF follow">Follow</button>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       $('#followUnFollow').on('click',function()
       {
           if($(this).hasClass('follow'))
               $(this).removeClass('follow').addClass('unfollow').text('Unfollow');
           else
               $(this).removeClass('unfollow').addClass('follow').text('Follow');           
       });
});
```

**UPDATE**

If you want the same on `hover` instead of click you can change `.on('click'` to `hover` as below:

```
$('#followUnFollow').hover(function(){
  ......
});
```

Comment: This is my code pen link
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aONqyR

What I want now is, When I hover over the Follow button then it should show the unfollow button and when clicked the unfollow btn on hover state then it should remove the whole element box. 
How can this be achieved using jquery?

Comment: By mentioning _whole element box_ do you mean the div with the class `foll-container`? I mean you want to remove that div??

Comment: Nope. I want '.foll' to disappear

Comment: Hmm... Thats Great. But What About having to columns like  this http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aONqyR

Answer (score 2):

Try following code:

It will hide the `click`ed button and show other button.

```
$('.btn-follow').on('click', function () {
    $(this).hide();
    $('.btn-unfollow').show();
});
$('.btn-unfollow').on('click', function () {
    $(this).hide();
    $('.btn-follow').show();
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/Ls8gk2es/

Answer (score 1):

I think using hover event you can make it simpler.

**HTML**

```
<button class="btn btn-follow">Follow</button>
<button class="btn btn-unfollow">Unfollow</button>
```

**JS**

```
$('.btn-unfollow').hide();
$('.btn').hover(function () {
    $('.btn').toggle();
});
```

**CSS** (same as the styling given in your question)

Answer (score 0):

Its pretty easy with jquery.  Just use jquery .hover()

```
$( ".btn-follow" ).hover(
  function() {
    $( this ).addClass('btn-unfollow');
    $( this ).html( 'Unfollow' );
  }, function() {
    $( this ).removeClass('btn-unfollow');
    $( this ).html( 'Follow' );;
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can play with

```
.mouseenter()
.mouseleave()
```

in order to trigger the event

and then `.addClass`
and `.removeClass`

to apply or remove your css classes.

Answer (score 0):

How about using js like this:

```
$('btn-follow').on('mouseover', function(){
    this.hide();
    $('btn-unfollow').show();
});

$('btn-unfollow').on('mouseover', function(){
    this.hide();
    $('btn-follow').show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {     
        $('.btn-follow').mouseover( function(){

            $(this).hide();
            $('.btn-unfollow').show();
        });

        $('.btn-unfollow').mouseover(function(){
            $(this).hide();
            $('.btn-follow').show();
        }); 
    });
```